# How to color entire navbar Page in shiny

Tags: shiny, navbar, background-color

The following code does almost exactly what I want:

```
ui <- fluidPage(

  tags$style(HTML(".navbar{background-color: #690a20;}")),

  navbarPage(
    title='Navbar',

    tabPanel(
      title = "start page",

      fillPage(
        fluidRow(style = "background-color: #690a20;color: white;",
                 br(),
                 br(),
                 headerPanel(h1("WELCOME", align='center')),
                 h4("Thank you for participating",
                    align='center'),
                 br(),
                 br(),
                 br())
   ))))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {})

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

But I want to get rid of the white strip between the navigation bar and the fluidpage.
Does anyone has an idea to do this?
I tried it by hiding the navigation bar, but this still leaves a tiny strip.

Answer (score 0):

Will this suffice?

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(

    tags$style(HTML(".navbar{margin:0px;background-color: #690a20;}")),
    navbarPage(
        title='Navbar',
        tabPanel(
            title = "start page",
            fillPage(
                fluidRow(style = "background-color: #690a20;color: white;",
                         br(),
                         br(),
                         headerPanel(h1("WELCOME", align='center')),
                         h4("Thank you for participating",
                            align='center'),
                         br(),
                         br(),
                         br())
            ))))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {})

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]

Comment: If possible, I would like to not have this tiny white strip. Or in the best case, just hide the navigation bar for the start-page.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to came up with a solution to my problem:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)


ui <- fluidPage(

  useShinyjs(),
  tags$style(type='text/css', "nav.navbar.navbar-default.navbar-static-top{border-color: #f5f5f5;background-color: #f5f5f5;}"),
  tags$style(type='text/css', ".navbar{min-height: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px;}"),
  tags$style(type='text/css', ".navbar-brand{height: 0px; padding: 0px 0px;}"),


  tags$style(HTML(".navbar{background-color: #690a20;}")),

  navbarPage(
    title=NULL, id="navigation-bar",

    tabPanel(
      title = "start page",

      fillPage(
        fluidRow(style = "background-color: #690a20;color: white;",
                 br(),
                 br(),
                 headerPanel(h1("WELCOME", align='center')),
                 h4("Thank you for participating",
                    align='center'),
                 br(),
                 br(),
                 br())
      ))))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

  observe(
    {
      hide(selector = "#navigation-bar")
    })
})


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```